# configure omnicomplete to use `gj` `gk` to go the next and previous completion

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

Having decided to use the arrow keys to navigate instead of hjkl, and having decided that I want to move to the previous screen line, not actual text line, I have put this on vimrc

```
nnoremap <Up>   gk
nnoremap <Down> gj
xnoremap <Up>   gk
xnoremap <Down> gj
inoremap <Up>   <C-o>gk
inoremap <Down> <C-o>gj
```

This conflicts with omnicomplete, because it wants to use the arrows to navigate the completions offered. I can still navigate with `CTRL-N` and `CTRL-P`, but I much would prefer to use the arrows to choose my autocompletion. Is there any way to configure omnicomplete to use my `gj` `gk`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using an [expression mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression) to send CTRL-N/CTRL-P during completion. e.g.

```
:inoremap <expr> <Up> pumvisible() ? '<C-P>' : '<C-O>gk'
:inoremap <expr> <Down> pumvisible() ? '<C-N>' : '<C-O>gj'
```

Comment: Sorry, the OP wanted to type gj to move down in the popup; yet, you might want to type an actual g. This would be annoying (to me at least) so mapping other keys is a better idea.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think the OP actually wants to use up and down in the popup, and they asked how to configure the popup to accept the mapping’s *rhs* `gj` in order to achieve this. I’ve tackled it a different way (because their suggestion isn’t possible).

Comment: Oooohhh. My bad. Really misread that.

Comment: Yes, I do not want to use `g` or `gj` ever in my life. Sorry bad habits, but hard to remove. I wish I can do everything with arrow keys.